# React props function becomes undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a function defined in a parent component. I'm passing the function to child components. When I call the function in the child component, I have the error:
`TypeError: updateModifiers is not a function`

Logging the `typeof` show that the function is defined at the first render, then become undefined in the next two renders:

```
function
undefined
undefined
```

Why would be the reason `updateModifiers` is overwritten? I have no clue what is going on..

```js
const Product = ({
    ...
}) => {
    ...

    const updateModifiers = (modifierId, options) => {
        ...
    }

    return (
        <Drawer anchor="bottom" open={open} onClose={closeDrawer}>
            ...
            <ProductModifiers current={selection} updateModifiers={updateModifiers} />
            ...
        </Drawer>
    )
}

export default Product

const ProductModifiers = ({ current, updateModifiers }) => {
    console.log("parent", typeof updateModifiers)

    if (Object.keys(current.modifiers).length === 0)
        return null

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {Object.values(current.modifiers).sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order).map((modifier, i) =>
                <ProductModifier key={i} modifier={modifier} updateModifiers={updateModifiers} />
            )}
        </Fragment>
    )
}

const ProductModifier = ({ modifier, updateModifiers }) => {
    console.log("child", modifier.name, typeof updateModifiers)
    ...

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(typeof updateModifiers) // <-- returns function -> undefined -> undefined
        // updateModifiers(modifier.name, options)
    }, [options])

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

**UPDATE**: (if it helps)

The `Object.values(current.modifiers)` in `ProductModifiers` have two elements. For the first element, the function is well defined. For the second, not.

```
parent function
child Toppings function
child Toppings function
child Sides undefined
child Sides undefined
parent function
child Toppings function
child Toppings function
child Sides undefined
child Sides undefined
```

Why would `updateModifiers` be undefined in the second rendered component?

**UPDATE2**:

Found the issue. Related to my code somewhere else. Still, asking the question helped me to debug! ;-)

Comment: You shouldn't be passing updateModifiers like that, if it did work it could cause the application to loop forever. I would use `useContext` for something like this.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible issue using Sandbox?

Comment: @PrateekThapa this is not the same code but it follows the same pattern: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-wu-fp7yp?file=/src/App.js. However, in that sandbox, it works. So I hope someone had the same issue in the past...

Comment: @nzajt I think useContext would be an overkill solution. Why would you expect a loop? It is not looping currently..

Comment: @Binajmen  There is some problem in your code and how you implement it. The above code looks okay with a open eye. Do create a provide a reproducible issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to remove the drawer component to check if it doesn't introduce some side effects on the ProductModifiers?

Comment: Changing with `<div>` throws me the error directly :(

Comment: I just don't get why the function is defined at the first render, then becomes undefined... In the `ProductModifiers` if I put a `console.log(typeof updateModifiers)` I have `function` once in the console. In `ProductModifier`, function -> undefined -> undefined. The last two renders are somehow overwritting something...

Comment: Could you double check Drawer doesn't have any side effect? I have tried a similar setup to yours and type seems to be correctly displayed: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-frog-siei7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the **componentDidMount** & **componentDidUpdate** logics. In fact, the componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted, but when the component has changed, you should handle the componentDidUpdate() logic.

To handle both componentDidMount & componentDidUpdate, in your ProductModifier component try this:

```
    const ProductModifier = ({ modifier, updateModifiers }) => {
    const mounted = useRef();
    ...

    useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current) {
      // do componentDidMount logic
      mounted.current = true;
    } else {
      // do componentDidUpdate logic
    }
  });

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: ? I'm using useEffect(.., [var]) to handle mount and update events. I don't see how it helps me in my current problem..